# Where can i get DOTNET Platform 5.4 assembly?

Tags: .net

I was tasked to add functionality to a POC application that our architect has started, he used VS2015 for it. When i was finally able to install and open the sln that he created, i can't compile it because im missing the .NET PLATFORM 5.4 reference in one of the projects. I tried searching online and via NUGET but i can't seem to get a straight forward answer on what I am lacking/ missing and what i need to install to get DOTNET PLATFORM 5.4

Answer (score 0):

You won't get this profile unless you are also using Visual a Studio 2015 right now with latest NuGet 3.x.

NuGet is smart enough to expand the assemblies referred in projec.json file and hint the IDE and compiler to locate the proper API surface.

Comment: I have VS2015 and tried to search it using NUGET which i wasn't able to resolve.

I also downloaded DOTNET core installer and still not fixed.

Comment: @user1465073 post the project.json file and the compilation error. Without that there is no much we can talk about, as so many people get it working.

Comment: i finally got it working, the reason was Automapper 4.2.0 that was installed via NUGET by one of the people working in the project and checked-it in. As of this writing, Automapper doesn't support DOTNET PLATFORM 5.4, only up to 4.5.x. When i removed that NUGET package everything worked.

Comment: @user1465073 yes, many existing libraries would require migration efforts from their authors. Then all kinds of applications can start to migrate.

Comment: i see, i just installed VS2015 this morning and still exploring things.

Comment: Thank you everyone